# add hover-over text for label of virtualSelectInput in r shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, hover, selectinput

I'm trying to add a hover-over text to my shiny app. Specifically, I want to add it to the label of the virtualSelectInput (which is the label above the drop-down selection).

I have found posts on how to add hover-over text to the CHOICES in the drop down selection, but so far I haven't been able to find anything that shows how to do this with the label itself. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Relevant part of my code:

```
div(
    useShinyjs(),
     virtualSelectInput(
      inputId = ns("benchmark_population"),
      label = "Select Benchmark Population: ",
      choices = NULL,
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = FALSE,
      search = FALSE,
      placeholder = "Benchmark Population"
    ),
```

So far, I've tried various approaches such as shinyWidgets::pickerInput instead of virtualSelectInput and then shiny::p("This is the sub-title for the benchmark population selection"), neither of which are doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack would be to lean on the html `title` attribute. When you hover over the div you'll see the title.

This is untested since no reproducible data was provided.

```
div(
    title = "Test Benchmark Population", # add a title to the div
    useShinyjs(),
     virtualSelectInput(
      inputId = ns("benchmark_population"),
      label = "Select Benchmark Population: ",
      choices = NULL,
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = FALSE,
      search = FALSE,
      placeholder = "Benchmark Population"
    ),
```

**Example**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(
    title = "this is a test",
    selectInput("test",label = "Test",choices = 1:5, selected = 1)
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input ID of your `virtualSelect` is `MYID` then the label ID is `MYID-label`. Once you have a HTML id on an element, you can use `bsTooltip` in the package `shinyBS`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
  virtualSelectInput(
    inputId = "MYID",
    label = "Single select :",
    choices = month.name,
    search = TRUE
  ),
  bsTooltip(
    id = "MYID-label",
    "Hello select something please"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```